# Is g++ -Wdangling-reference warning justified in this case?

Tags: c++, reference, g++, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

Compiling my code with *gcc 13.2* and `-Wdangling-reference` I was surprised that in this simple scenario ([godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/77aEPEWYf)):

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::string& add_variable(std::vector<std::string>& vars, const std::string& var)
   {
    vars.push_back( var );
    return vars.back();
   }

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vars;
    const std::string& var = add_variable(vars, "name");
}
```

The compiler warns that:

```
<source>:13:41: warning: possibly dangling reference to a temporary [-Wdangling-reference]
   13 |     const std::string& var = add_variable(vars, "name");
      |                        ^~~
<source>:13:59: note: the temporary was destroyed at the end of the full expression 'add_variable(vars, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>(((const char*)"name"), std::allocator<char>()))'
   13 |     const std::string& var = add_variable(vars, "name");
      |
```

Is this a false positive or there's something big I'm missing here?

Comment: note - although this specific example does seem to be a false positive; if you call `add_variable` again in main, then `var` would dangle if the vector `push_back` causes reallocation

Comment: @M.M indeed, this API is prone to possible misuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it looks like a false positive. `var` is referencing the `std::string` in your `vector<string>` which is still very much alive after the full expression.

Comment: that's a relief, I'll sleep better now :-)

Comment: @MatG :-) The odd thing is that  gcc only thinks it's a dangling ref because it's a `const&`. Remove `const` from `var` in `main` and it'll be happy.

Comment: You're right! I wouldn't have thought of that in a million years

Comment: @MatG I'm surprised too. Converting a `std::string&` to a `std::string const&` shouldn't create a temporary. Very odd.

Comment: @MatG There are already a few [bugreports](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=dangling-reference) regarding this so I won't file another one.